# Typescript: check if a value was returned by a specific function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

E.g. I want to tell whether a value was returned by React's `useCallback`, which memoizes functions. I'm using this hack:

```
type UseCallback<T extends AnyFunction> = T & { __IS_USE_CALLBACK: true };

declare function useCallback<T extends AnyFunction>(
  callback: T,
  deps: ReadonlyArray<any>,
): UseCallback<T>;
```

This allows me to do:

```
function Component({ foo }: { foo: UseCallback<() => void> }) {}

// Ok
<Component foo={useCallback(() => {}, [])} />

// Error
<Component foo={() => {}} />
```

However, using `__IS_USE_CALLBACK` is obviously very hacky. Also, I can't use the same approach for `useMemo` unless it's an object. Is there a better to tell if a value was returned by a specific function?

Comment: What you're using is called "branded types" and it's fairly normal in TS, if slightly rare. The more general thing you seem to want is called *nominal types* as in, types that are different just by name (so `UseCallbac<T>` is a different one from `T` even if they can otherwise be used the same way). [See here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping). Also called *opaque types* because they cannot be assigned to each other. See also [this approach here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/) which is my personal favourite.

Comment: @VLAZ so that's the same thing as what I'm doing right? The second approach makes `__IS_USE_CALLBACK` optional, which I wouldn't want. It's great that I know what it's called now, thanks!